# Print out a given argument files content in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char** alllines;
    int size=0;
    if(argc < 2){
        
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
            FILE* fp;
            unsigned int bufferSize = 1024;
            char* line = malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferSize);                
            char* filename = argv[i];
            fp = fopen(filename, "r");
            if (fp == NULL)
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

            while (getline(&line, &bufferSize, fp) != -1){          
                printf("%s", line);
            }
            fclose(fp);
            if (line)
                free(line);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }  
    return(0);
}
```

Here's how I compile and run the code:

`gcc program.c`

Here's how I run it:

`./a.exe test.txt`

Here's the test file(it's in the same directory as the c file):

```
12345
asddfhdfh
abcdefgh
765431
```

Here's what it returns:
`MZÉ$`

Here's what it should return:

```
12345
asddfhdfh
abcdefgh
765431
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is the path to your executable file and `MZ...binary mess` is a .exe header. Start `i` at 1.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks.

Comment: `argv[0]` might not even be a path. It's the name that was used on the command line, which could be different if the executable is found via `$PATH`.

Comment: There's no need for the `malloc` call. You can pass NULL to `getline` and it will do the initial allocation for you.